# Hibernate throws servlet service default exception when configuration instance is created

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, struts2

While creating an instance of the configuration instance of hibernate in Struts2 Servlet service error is thrown. This is the error I got. When ever instance of configuration class present in the `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration` package is created the following error is shown and cannot be resolved.

```
Dec 18, 2015 4:42:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator not found
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:214)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$400(ServiceLoader.java:164)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:350)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:421)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(IntegratorServiceImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:213)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:119)
    at hibernateTest.HibernateTestController.<init>(HibernateTestController.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:158)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:178)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.DefaultActionFactory.buildAction(DefaultActionFactory.java:22)
...
```

Any suggestion is much appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It occured to me when the `hibernate.cfg.xml` was not in the correct path.

- Add the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file to the classpath.(You could put it to the 'resources' folder.)
- If the `hibernate.cfg.xml` is already in the class path, try passing the file name as a parameter to the configuration.

  ```
       Configuration configuration = new Configuration();  
       configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
  ```
- If you want to use a different path for the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file, do as follows.

  ```
  String hibernatePropsFilePath = "/etc/configs/hibernate.cfg.xml";
  File hibernatePropsFile = new File(hibernatePropsFilePath);

  Configuration configuration = new Configuration(); 
  configuration.configure(hibernatePropsFile);
  ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ tharindu_DG even before I call the configure method I get the error. This occurs as soon as the new Configuration() is executed.

Comment: did u try the solution that i proposed?

Comment: Yes I tried it but still the same exception is thrown  @tharindu_DG